# Dynamic PHP URLS (not using variables)

Tags: php, html, apache, http, https

Is anyone able to explain to me how to create dynamic page URLS with PHP that do not use variables at the end of the URL?

For example how could I website with the following URL work?

```
https://www.discogs.com/user/<username>/collection
```

Surely it's not that a folder exists for all users within the /users/ directory, so how is this done?

Another example I can think of is URL shorteners which must store data in a database. E.g. `bit.ly/3vjqTCR`

Apologies if this has been answered many times before, but I'm not sure what to search for to find the answer.

Comment: I use `mod_rewrite` to route all requests to a `deliver.php`. There are MANY ways to route once you're in `deliver.php`. A simple example is like: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/blog/happy-cats/')echo "content of happy cats blog post"; else if (...url...==='/user/jenny/')...`. Its common to use a framework like Laravel or Symfony or one of many others. I personally developed my own framework that lets me route in various ways. You could also look for a simple [router library](https://github.com/search?q=router+php) that JUST does routing (& not all the extra stuff frameworks do)

Comment: By "variables" I think you're referring to "query paramaters" (`?param=value&param2=value2`). For that specific case (`/user/<username>/collection/`), you might have a users database. Parse the url & determine to load the `user.collection` template for `<username>` & load that user from the database, passing it to the template.

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty new to programming, or at least to PHP. It might be helpful to do a skillshare course or follow some Youtube tutorials or something. There's a lot of fundamentals you might gain from a few good tutorials that would take awhile to pick up if going the "search for what I need when I need it" route. But also don't get yourself stuck in tutorial land. I think once fundamentals are down fairly well, tutorials are much less helpful (but I rarely have used tutorials, so I'm not the best person to ask on that).